# With Mike Hearn quitting Bitcoin, what seems to be the future of bitcoinj?

Tags: bitcoinj

Mike Hearn has apparently sold all his Bitcoins. So what is to be expected about the development of bitcoinj? (and Java based clients in general).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hopefully, `bitcoinj` will now be maintained by [other people](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/graphs/contributors) that based projects on it. From what I've read and the [commit list](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/commits/master) it seems that Andreas Schildbach, who also initiated the Bitcoin Wallet for Android, now takes a leading role in maintaining of bitcoinj.